# Sort an array alphabetically and return a number representation for every character

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-representation

I want to try to make my own function.
I want to sort an array of characters in increasing order and return the occurrence count of each character as a compact number.

Example:

```
function numberRepresentation(arr) {
    // arr is an array
    // return a number

    /*
    ex. arr=[b,a,a,a,c,b,a]
    after sorting array will look like arr=[a,a,a,a,b,b,c]
    occurrence of characters -> a = 4, b = 2, c = 1 
    so output will be 421
    */
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you show us what you've tried so far and what part of this you're having problems with? Check out the [help] for info on how to ask a good question

Comment: Why 421 and not 241 for example? Is it because `a < b < c` or because `count(a) > count(b) > count(c)`? In other words, which output would you need for `[a,b,b]`?

Comment: if arr = [a,b,b], the output should be 12

Answer (score 0):

```js
function numberRepresentation(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((counts, letter) => {
        const code = letter.charCodeAt(0)
        counts[code] = counts[code] + 1 || 1
        return counts
    }, []).join('')
}
```

Explanation:

We just count occurrence of every letter, but we use a simple Array and char codes as indexes. Thus we automatically get a list of counts of letters ordered alphabetically (because the char codes go in abc order). So all we need to do is concatenate all the counts and return.

Comment: whoever put a minus explain what you didn't like?

Comment: You have, whether intentionally or not, managed to find a solution that doesnt require sorting though. You deserve points for that!

Comment: @Jamiec yes I made a solution without sorting intentionally because it's the most optimal way. I checked your fiddle, don't see any issues. It works with no errors.